# Plotting a Function Over Multiple Constants

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, plot, scipy

I'm trying to plot my function `f(x)` using multiple values for the only constant all on one graph. I've done this before, and it worked fine. But when using the same method using this function, I get an error saying

> x and y must have same first dimension, but have shapes (1000,) and (1,)

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import scipy as s

x = s.linspace(0,2* s.pi, 1000)
m = [1.1, 1.2, 1.3, 1.5, 2.0]
m = s.asarray(m)
m = m[:, s.newaxis]

def f(x): 
    return [m**2 /(4*s.cos(x/2))] [ (m*s.cos(x/2) - 1)*(m - s.cos(x/2))] / (1 + m**2 - 2*m*s.cos(x/2))**2

plt.plot(x,m[0], x,m[1], x,m[2], x,m[3], x,m[4])
plt.show()
```

---

EDIT:

When trying to set `m=1.1` instead of the list, and plotting it for one value of `m` only, I get the following error message.

> TypeError: only integer scalar arrays can be converted to a scalar index

Here is my code for that.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import scipy as s

x = s.linspace(0,2* s.pi, 1000)
m=1.1

def f(x): 
    return [m**2 /(4*s.cos(x/2))] [ (m*s.cos(x/2) - 1)*(m - s.cos(x/2))] / ( 1 + m**2 - 2*m*s.cos(x/2))**2

plt.plot(x,f(x))
plt.show()
```

Does this shed any light on what my problem is?

---

What am I doing wrong here?
Thanks!

Comment: If you want to have it working with minimal changes use a singleton list `m=[1.1] `

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pass the constant as a parameter:

```
def f(x, m):
    numerator = m**2*(m*s.cos(x/2) - 1)*(m - s.cos(x/2))
    denominator = 4*s.cos(x/2)*(1 + m**2 - 2*m*s.cos(x/2))**2
    return numerator/denominator

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
m_arr = s.asarray([1.1, 1.2, 1.3, 1.5, 2.0])
for const_m in m_arr:
    ax.plot(x, f(x, const_m))
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think your function is returning what you want it to. In your return call, you're trying to index into your first array using calculated values, which is giving you the `TypeError: only integer scalar arrays can be converted to a scalar index` error
e.g. `[1,2,3,4][1]` gives you `2` but `[1,2,3,4][1.5]` throws an error.

If I use your original array to index in, I get nice, clean lines based on the value constants

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import scipy as s

x = s.linspace(0,2* s.pi, 1000)
m = [1.1, 1.2, 1.3, 1.5, 2.0]
m = np.array(m).reshape(-1,1)

def f(x): 
    return  np.array([m**2 /(4*s.cos(x/2))][0]).T.dot(np.array([ (m*s.cos(x/2) - 1)*(m - s.cos(x/2))] / (1 + m**2 - 2*m*s.cos(x/2))**2)[0])

plt.plot(x,m[0]*x, x,m[1]*x, x,m[2]*x, x,m[3]*x, x,m[4]*x)
plt.show()
```

[plot here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4UFQL.png)

Comment: There is something wrong here, the plot it gives is incorrect. It should look like the plot produced by @PMende. Over the range -pi/2 < x < pi/2, it should look like this:  https://imgur.com/bBB27CK

Comment: Yeah, I just passed in the constant from your original array m to show that the issue was with the return from the function, but that the rest of the code was sound. Apologies for being unclear.

Comment: Oh, that makes sense. Sorry, I guess I misunderstood.